# Can't import PunktSentenceTokenizer from nltk.corpus

Tags: python, nltk, pos-tagger

I tried to import as:

```
from nltk.corpus import PunktSentenceTokenizer
```

This gave me the below error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'PunktSentenceTokenizer'
```

Now I tried to import it as:

```
tokenizer = nltk.tokenize.punkt.PunktSentenceTokenizer()
```

but the below code gives error again:

```
tagged_sentences = nltk.corpus.treebank.tagged_sents()

cutoff = int(.75 * len(tagged_sentences))
training_sentences = DataPrep.train_news['Statement']

print(training_sentences)
custom_sent_tokenizer =tokenizer.tokenize(training_sentences)
tokenized=custom_sent_tokenizer
error is: #TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Comment: To fix your first error: Use `from nltk.tokenize.punkt import PunktSentenceTokenizer`. And how do your `training_sentences` look like? The error states that you need to pass a string or byte object to the function.

Comment: its seems type of ```training_sentences``` is not string. Please verify it again.